# How to recognize an error when saving cmd result from command prompt as a string in python?

Tags: python-3.x, exception, command-prompt

This code runs python commands in command prompt and saves the output as a string:

```
output = subprocess.run(
        ["python3", "-c", "print("hello")\njj" ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, timeout=3)
    output = output.stdout.decode('utf-8')
print(output)
```

The output will be:

```
hello
```

In my own cmd I get the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
NameError: name 'jj' is not defined
```

I tried writing a try and except but it won't work either.

I would like for the output to catch the error as well, it will look like this:

```
hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
NameError: name 'jj' is not defined
```

Comment: Why are you running a new python interpreter from inside python using `subprocess`? There are much nicer ways to run python code from inside python...

Comment: For example..? I don't want to open a new file

Comment: Why not just put the 'broken' print line in a try/except block? Why wrap it in a new python interpreter? you probably need to explain what it is you want to achieve, as this is looking like an X/Y problem.

Comment: In my program I don't know the actual code, I can only get it via a string

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the most practical but this is what I ended up doing:

```
txt_str = 'print("hello")\njj'.split("\n")
command = "\t".join([txt + \n for txt in txt_str])
command = "try:\n" \
         "\t%s\n" \
         "except Exception as e:\n" \
         "\tprint(e)" % (command, )
output = subprocess.run(
    ["python3", "-c", command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, timeout=3)
output = output.stdout.decode('utf-8')
```